# Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Let $\operatorname{rank}(A)=s$ and $\operatorname{rank}(B)=t$. Then rank of $A+B\ge\cdots$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices. Let $\rank(A)=s$ and $\rank(B)=t$. Then rank of $A+B$ is at least ..............

**My attempt**

- $\rank(A)=s$  $\implies$ $A$ has $s$ linearly independent $n\times 1$ column vectors. Let it be $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_s\}$
- $\rank(B)=t$  $\implies$ $B$ has $t$ linearly independent $n\times 1$ column vectors. Let it be $\{y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_t\}$

How do I complete the question?

Comment: if $s>t$ very likely $s-t$

Comment: $\lvert s-t\rvert$ with no assumption on which is the bigger of $s,t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general low bound. If $B=-A$, then $A+B=0$ with rank $0$ independently of the rank of $A$. For different $s,t$ you can probably expect $rank(A+B)\ge |s-t|$. To prove  (or disprove) it, you can assume that, say, $A$ is in the RREF.

Comment: That also holds for $s=t$.

Comment: The rank is non-negative always, so it is not very illuminating.

Answer (score 0):

I find the conclusion of $R(A+B)\leq R(A)+R(B)$ on page 69 of [this book](http://book.ucdrs.superlib.net/views/specific/2929/bookDetail.jsp?dxNumber=000004937296&d=7EC730F56E3D971C8F377B4263F41927&fenlei=18060101). As for the lower bound, it should be $  \left|s-t \right| $.

[image]